# SharePoint 2013: Document set shared columns not behaving

Tags: document-set

I have a Project 'document set' which gets created just fine and 4 project documents are created within the DocSet. There is a workflow that runs during the DocSet creation that assigns a project number (Column: Project Number) to the DocSet. 'Project Number' is shared with the associated child content types within the DocSet content type.

Issue: A workflow has been created with the intent of assigning a project number to the document set. However, the workflow treats the DocSet child documents as individual items and assigns a unique project number to each document. Then when the DocSet gets a project number assigned to it, it refreshes the children within the DocSet and everything matches (because of the share). But its wrong as the project number has incremented by 5.

Any thoughts what is going on here? I'm a bit dumbfounded.

Kind regards,

Comment: What is the workflow type? When does it trigger?

Comment: Type = List Workflow. Triggers upon doc set creation. 
Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

Note - Document set (DS), Document Set Documents (DSD), workflow (WF).

Use the column “content type” as a check in the workflow. I think it’s a reserved column at the application level.
All DS and DSD get processed by the WF, but the “content type” check restricts it to the value designated in the DS.

Ok… moving on….
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should make it as a reusable workflow and make it start in creation of doc set content type. So this workflow will not run for  the documents and only run once for each document set.

Comment: I tried as suggested but the results are the same. 

The DocSet and DocSetDocs all get work flowed. The WF starts with one of the DocSetDocs and assigns the project number. Then the next DocSetDoc (next project number in sequence). Then the DocSet itself (next project number in sequence), and because the DocSet shares the project number it overwrites the DocSetDoc project numbers, so everything properly matches.

I guess I need to have the DocSet not create the DocSetDocs oncreation. Leave it to the user to use the "New" menu and insert the selection of DocSetDocs.